# json causes problem in IE

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

I'm using this bit of javascript with json string to send data to flash project

```
        var flashvars = { 
        xmlFile: 'http://iyt.psu.edu/xml/abington/home.xml',
        preface: 'http://iyt.psu.edu/',
        preload: '{"url":"flash/project.swf","x":"375","y":"237","link":"home","tween":{"prop":"y","begin":"0","finish":"-200","duration":"1"}}'
    };
```

however the preload line causes problems in IE anyone have any idea what I"m might be doing wrong besides using IE ; ^ )

Comment: Why do you have a json string in a json object?

Comment: Well... you are using IE. But you already know that. ;)

Comment: Is preload property supposed to be string or object? If object it should not be enclosed between quotes (single quotes around the { ... }.

Comment: Neither IE7 nor IE8 complain about that code when I try it. I suggest that the problem diagnosis may need reexamination.

Comment: @mcgrailm - clarify something please: does IE complain about the code you posted, or about the string value of "preload" when you pass it to some JSON decoder or something?

Comment: the preload assignment is a json string just a string that gets pasted to flash then parsed as json within the flash project

Comment: IE doesn't give any error message my project just fails to load if I take out the json string it loads fine

Comment: How about adding in portions on the JSON string until IE fails to load? should help you locate where the problem is.

Comment: Well the thing is, there's nothing wrong with that string *as a JavaScript string constant.* If you're handing it over to something else, maybe the JSON parser is extremely strict.  JSON requires that forward-slash ("/") characters be escaped with a preceding backslash ("\").

Comment: @Pointy if it was the josn parser then it would work in any browser right ?

Comment: I don't know, @mcgrailm - I'm still not sure I understand exactly what it is you see happen. That code works fine when I feed it to IE, so ...

Comment: I found a work around by encoding the stirng then ie doesn't mangle it and the parser can still parse it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a trailing comma and you are using FireFox or a Webkit based browser then everything will look fine. But in IE any trailing commas with no more object properties will cause a problem that may not be so obvious.

This will fail. see the extra comma at the end:

```
var flashvars = { 
        "xmlFile" : "http://iyt.psu.edu/xml/abington/home.xml",
        "preface" : "http://iyt.psu.edu/",
        "preload" : "{'url': 'flash/project.swf' , 'x': '375 ', 'y': '237', 'link': 'home', 'tween' : {'prop':'y','begin' : '0', 'finish' : '-200' , 'duration' : '1' }}",
}
```

Also properly formatted JSON that passes the http://www.jslint.com/ test never hurts.

```
var flashvars = { 
        "xmlFile" : "http://iyt.psu.edu/xml/abington/home.xml",
        "preface" : "http://iyt.psu.edu/",
        "preload" : "{'url': 'flash/project.swf' , 'x': '375 ', 'y': '237', 'link': 'home', 'tween' : {'prop':'y','begin' : '0', 'finish' : '-200' , 'duration' : '1' }}"
}
```

But the JSON you pasted in looks ok. Also, maybe an apostrophe was included from a Word document.

Comment: changing the quotes around fixes the problem of ie passing the stirng probperly but then my actionsript json decoder breaks   var jsonData:Object = JSON.decode(jsontext) ;

Comment: this helped me out so +1 to you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it’s the `/` that needs to be escaped in JSON strings.

Comment: It doesn't have to be valid JSON; it's a JavaScript assignment statement. The contents of the "preload" variable looks like JSON to me, though strictly speaking JSON does require forward slash to be escaped (I don't know why).

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: According to [RFC 4627](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627#section-2.5) it isn’t.

Comment: great to know. Thanks for pointing this out. I wonder if this is the culprit here.

Comment: Well according to the OP's latest comments, it's just a JavaScript error of some sort. (Maybe.)

Answer (score 0):

actually you should encode the json string using server side or javascript tool and then AS3 will automatically decode it:

for example in JSP:

```
var flashvars = { 
        xmlFile: 'http://iyt.psu.edu/xml/abington/home.xml',
        preface: 'http://iyt.psu.edu/',
        preload: '<c:out value="{"url":"flash/project.swf","x":"375","y":"237","link":"home","tween":{"prop":"y","begin":"0","finish":"-200","duration":"1"}}'" />'
    };
```